# What is the standard way to control whether a pager is used by any program (capable of not using a pager)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

For specific applications one might have a flag or configuration that can be set, e.g. `git diff --no-pager`.

But I'm not looking to change any default behavior or anything. I'm just trying to force (for specific instances of scripted PTY events) output to come out non-interactively.

I can think of two approaches:

`command | cat` ... or ... `cat <(command)`

These commands are to be run in the PTY (specifically, they are sent to `tmux` via the script.sh, like `tmux new-window script.sh`), and this does in fact run it not like running a script (like how it is written) but as like actually typing it in.

I'm assuming that the first `cat` approach is actually going to fork out a program and make a pipe so that would probably be slower. As far as I can tell, though the second approach does the same thing. How can I get around use of cat? Is this an actual true useful use of `cat`??

I've thought of two more ways:

```
mkfifo fifo
command > fifo &
cat fifo
```

Alright, that one looks asinine and is long-hand for `|`.

```
command > file &
tail -f file
```

How to know when the file is done being written to?

```
rm -f file
touch file
tail -f file &
PID=$!
command >> file
kill $PID
```

Quite circuitous.

Are there any other possible methods? Which one is best?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to assign `cat` to `$PAGER`, so that any correctly-written apps just dump their output.

```
export PAGER=cat
```

Comment: Oooooh, this is neat! I wonder if there are any programs that don't check PAGER but can still be de-interactivized. I know, for example, that I can actually do stuff like `printf "\n" | vim -c ":BundleInstall"`, to make Vim accept an Enter (for dismissing an error message that appears on loading a bad configuration), and that  is an example of some out-of-band cleverness not covered by this answer

Comment: Also... still uses cat. Can I avoid cat, maybe? (cuz otherwise I'd just rather pipe it to cat because I feel like there is a higher chance that would work correctly)

Comment: These programs expect something in `$PAGER` that they can pipe into; cat is simply the most convenient choice for something that echos its input unmodified.